# NamedPipeClientStream.Write blocks

Tags: c#, ipc

I'm just trying to understand pipes in C#. I've a simple LinqPad script:

```
void Main() =>  Program.Main(null);

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartServer();
            Task.Delay(1000).Wait();

            //Client
            var client = new NamedPipeClientStream("PipesOfPiece");
            client.Connect();

            while (true)
            {
                string input = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) break;
                
                var someBuffer = new byte[4];
                client.Write(someBuffer, 0, someBuffer.Length);
                "Client 1st Write".Dump();
                
                client.Write(someBuffer, 0, someBuffer.Length);
                "Client 2nd Write".Dump();
                
                client.Read(someBuffer, 0, someBuffer.Length);
                "Client 1st Read".Dump();
            }
        }

        static void StartServer()
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var server = new NamedPipeServerStream("PipesOfPiece");
                server.WaitForConnection();
                var someBuffer = new byte[4];
                while (true)
                {
                    server.Read(someBuffer, 0, someBuffer.Length);
                    "Server 1st Read".Dump();
                    server.Write(someBuffer, 0, someBuffer.Length);
                    "Server 1st Write".Dump();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

If I run above code I get following output:

```
Client 1st Write
Server 1st Read
```

So the second call on `client.Write` blocks forever. Can someone please explain me why a second call to write (in the same thread) causes the pipe to block forever?

Thx

Comment: What is `Dump()`?

Comment: `Stream.Write` is a synchronous method, ie it blocks. If you want to avoid blocking, use `WriteAsync`. You have to change the signature to `static async Task Main`.

Answer (score 0):

Its root cause is according to [synchrozniation context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/february/msdn-magazine-parallel-computing-it-s-all-about-the-synchronizationcontext) and thread switch blocking issues.
Do it like this dude:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
        StartServer();
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        //Client
        var client = new NamedPipeClientStream("PipesOfPiece");
        await client.ConnectAsync();

        while (true)
        {
            string input = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) break;

            var someBuffer = new byte[4];
            await client.WriteAsync(someBuffer, 0, someBuffer.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Client 1st Write");

            await client.WriteAsync(someBuffer, 0, someBuffer.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Client 2nd Write");

            await client.ReadAsync(someBuffer, 0, someBuffer.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Client 1st Read");

            //await Task.Delay(100);

        }
    }

    static void StartServer()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            var server = new NamedPipeServerStream("PipesOfPiece");
            await server.WaitForConnectionAsync();

            var someBuffer = new byte[4];
            while (true)
            {
                await server.ReadAsync(someBuffer, 0, someBuffer.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("Server 1st Read");
                await server.WriteAsync(someBuffer, 0, someBuffer.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("Server 1st Write");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I get the some output as with the sync. example `Client 1st Write
Server 1st Read`. So the second `WriteAsync` seems to be deadlocked.

Comment: Dear Moerwald unfortunately I can not understand what you say, please clarify your words